How can I cache a resource-hungry process with RxJs?
I have a resource-hungry process and I want to cache the latest result for a certain amount of time.
In following example I have the observable getInterval . This should be the resource-hungry process. The result of the observable gets shared via getSharedInterval. This last emission is cached for 5 seconds.
But what I want to achieve, is that the getInterval observable should complete immediately when the outer observable unscrubscibes, but the latest result should be cached for the next 5 seconds.
Is this possible?
const getInterval = new Observable((source) => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    source.next('next');
  }, 1000);

  source.add(() => {
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
}).pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('I am running')),
  finalize(() => console.log('completed'))
);

const getSharedInterval = getInterval.pipe(
  share({
    resetOnRefCountZero: () => timer(5000),
    connector: () => new ReplaySubject(1),
    resetOnComplete: true,
  })
);

getSharedInterval
  .pipe(
    take(1),
    tap(() => console.log('I dont no want anymore'))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);


Yes, it is possible via the shareReplay() operator. It accepts a second argument which is a timer for how long the cached data is kept.
However, after the cache expires, future subscribers will only receive null. So, it requires some additional code to "replace" the observable when the cache expires.
let reusedObservable$;
const replaceInterval = () => {
  reusedObservable$ = getInterval.pipe(
    take(1),
    shareReplay(1, 5000)
  );
  return reusedObservable$;
}

export function getSharedInterval() {
  return replaceInterval().pipe(
    first(
      null,
      defer(() => replaceInterval())
    ),
    mergeMap((d) => (isObservable(d) ? d : of(d)))
  );
}

getSharedInterval().pipe(
  take(1),
  tap(() => console.log('I don't want it anymore'))
)
.subscribe(console.log);

With this setup, the first subscriber triggers the first value to be emitted and cached for 5 seconds. Future subscribers within that 5 seconds will get the cached value.
Subscribers after 5 seconds will cause null to be emitted which invokes a replacement observable to be returned, restarting the cache cycle.
Credit to this article I discovered while researching this answer.

Unfortunately, this does not work if I want to have the next two emissions. (take(2))
